# drush migrate-manifest not found

Tags: drush, migrations

I'm trying to migrate a D7 site to D8 following this tut: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/migrating-taxonomy-drupal-7-to-drupal-8

When I run

`drush migrate-manifest manifest.yml --legacy-db-url=mysql://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@localhost/{dbname}`

I get the error:

The drush command 'migrate-manifest' could not be found.

I'm using drush version 8.0-dev. Installed via composer. I also tried version 7.* and got the same message plus "Drush 7.0.0 does not support Drupal 8." What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Now this has been moved to [Migrate Manifest module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_manifest). You can enable this module and use drush migrate-manifest command.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the Drush command was moved to the `migrate_tools` module - which is part of `migrate_plus` (can be downloaded from https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus). Use Drush master branch (suitable for Drupal 8) and download migrate_tools the module and you will be able to call the migrate-manifest command.

Comment: 'drush dl migrate_tools' gives me "No release history was found for the requested project (migrate_tools). Could not download requested project(s)." I'm using drush 8.0-dev installed via composer using dev-master. Google is not turning up anything for a migrate_tools module either.

Comment: My bad, forgot it's part of migrate_plus. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks itarato. Here's what got it working for me:

`drush dl migrate_plus`

`drush en migrate_tools -y`

In addition it seems if you are on beta-14 like I am you need a patch to eliminate the error "Error: Class 'Drupal\migrate\Event\MigrateEvents' not found"

`curl https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/dispatch_events_at_key-2535458-38.patch | git apply`