# The drush command 'migrate-manifest' could not be found

Tags: drush

Not sure if it's a dupe issue, couldn't find it. Just trying to run an upgrade in drush8 and get:

The drush command 'migrate-manifest' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.

Tried with previous 8.* version and got the same problem.

Comment: sorry, dupe in: drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191568/13448

Answer (score 1):

answering my own question, [this is now in the contrib module migrate-manifest](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191568/13448):